# How to validate just one checkbox?

Tags: javascript

I'm working on a piece of code from an open source library called gvalidator. The following checkbox validate function only works when I have two or more checkboxes. For some reason the if(elements[i]checked) line is not returning true when elements only has 1 object in the array.

Anyone have a guess as to why this is happening?  Thanks!

```
this.validate = function() {
    // Check if the form has a value set for this checkbox
    // by cycling through all of the checkboxes
    var elements = document.forms[0].elements[this.field.name];

    if(undefined == elements.length){
         x = elements;
        elements = new Array(x);
    }
    for (i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
      if (elements[i].checked) {
        document.write(elements[i].name);
        this.setState(ONEGEEK.forms.FIELD_STATUS_OK);
        return true;
      } else {
        if (this.modified !== true || !this.isRequired) {
          this.setState(ONEGEEK.forms.FIELD_STATUS_INFO);
        } else {
          this.setState(ONEGEEK.forms.FIELD_STATUS_EMPTY);
        }
      }
    }
    return false;
};
```

Comment: I think your `if (undefined == ...` line might cause problems. Can you confirm that it runs properly (`console.log` some stuff)?

Comment: yeah, i've tested it. it's working fine. it will go all the way to that second if statement then the document.write call only gets performed in there are two or more checkboxes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Jan was right... almost. The following is required in the function **validate** as the the form.elements function won't always return an array - it returns an element in the case there is only 1 match:

```
// Check if the form has a value set for this checkbox
// by cycling through all of the checkboxes
var elements = document.forms[0].elements[this.field.name];
if (elements.length === undefined) {
    elements = [ elements ];
}
```

It is also required in the **setup** function before it adds the validation events in the first place:

```
this.setup = function() {
   ...
   // Add events to ALL of the items      
   var elements = document.forms[0].elements[this.field.name];
   if (elements.length === undefined) {
       elements = [ elements ];
   }
   for (i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
       _du.addEvent(elements[i], 'click', this.applyFieldValidation(this));
       _du.addEvent(elements[i], 'click', this.applyContextInformation(this));
       _du.addEvent(elements[i], 'change', this.applyFieldModification(this));
   }
}
```

I have updated the source code at code http://code.google.com/p/gvalidator/, the latest binary is available for download here: http://code.google.com/p/gvalidator/downloads/list.

Answer (score 0):

There are some serious and some minor flaws in your code. This is how it should look like. Test this code and tell me if it still does not work and provide any error messages in the error console.

```
this.validate = function () {
  // Check if the form has a value set for this checkbox
  // by cycling through all of the checkboxes
  var elements = document.forms[0].elements[this.field.name];
  if (elements.length === undefined) {
      elements = [ elements ];
  }

  for (var i = 0, ii = elements.length; i < ii; ++i) {
    if (elements[i].checked) {
      document.write(elements[i].name);
      this.setState(ONEGEEK.forms.FIELD_STATUS_OK);
      return true;
    } else {
      if (this.modified !== true || !this.isRequired) {
        this.setState(ONEGEEK.forms.FIELD_STATUS_INFO);
      } else {
        this.setState(ONEGEEK.forms.FIELD_STATUS_EMPTY);
      }
    }
  }
  return false;
};
```

Comment: Thanks for the code. I tried it out, but it still requires two checkboxes to work. No errors. Just a warning that getAttributeNodeNS() is deprecated. I'm actually using getAttribute in another location.